# Error: Could not import settings

Tags: django, python-2.7, pytest

I'm switching a very large multi-package, multi-app Django (1.4.5) project from using Django's native test runner to py.test (2.3.5). The tests for the lowest level package, web-framework, were discovered and run with no errors after creating a setup.cfg (to manage the py.test options) and a conftest.py (to ignore setup.py). When running py.test (with a setup.cfg and conftest.py) on any higher level package, which all require web-framework, I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not import settings 'high_level_package.test_settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named web_framework.settings
```

I'm using a virtual environment, and web-framework is in the venv at the following location: ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

I've tried with the venv built in the package's root directory and with it built outside the project path, to no avail. Also, I can import web_framework.settings from the Python interactive command line in the higher level package's root directory.

My current conftest.py is just the following line: collect_ignore = ["setup.py"]
I've tried adding the following lines above it:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

I also tried hardcoding in the path to the web-framework package in the above sys.path.append.

Neither worked.

In case it's relevant, my setup.cfg is:

```
[pytest]
python_files = *test*.py
norecursedirs = node_modules ENV
addopts = --junitxml=python_result.xml, --doctest-modules
```

Edit:
Forgot to mention the traceback relationship. higher_level_package.test_settings imports higher_level_package.settings, which itself imports web_framework.settings.

Comment: This is maybe unrelated, but I found that if I wrote django scripts they wouldn't let me import mysite.settings unless I also set the environment variable as well: `os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "mysite.settings"`

Comment: That is true. In this case, though, the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is set and detected within py.test.

Answer (score 1):

in order to have it work you either need to have a develop-install of the worktree, or add . to the PYTHONPATH env var

Comment: This can be achieved with "pip install -e ." or "python setup.py develop".

Answer (score -1):

Change to the folder where your main python website module is located

```
django-admin runserver --settings=mysite.settings
```

where **mysite** was created by

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```